# Why Mata given more importance than Pita?

Tags: culture, children

We all know that in order to bring a child into this world we need need both a female and a male (not taking into consideration current scientific methodologies), agree that a woman nurtures the baby in her womb for 9 months (god made it that way), but after birth father plays very important role in the up-bringing of the child, so why only mothers get all the credit (normally) why not fathers? Why in our culture is a mother portrayed as if all sacrifices are made by her?

Comment: Because- पितुः शतगुणा माता गौरवे चेति निश्चितम् ।
मातुः शतगुणः पूज्यो ज्ञानदाता गुरुः प्रभो ॥ ६ ॥ - 100 times a father is One Mother, this is certain. And 100 times a Mother is One Guru, who gives knowledge. - DeviPuraana, 9 book, Chapter 38.

Comment: @AnuragSingh But we can not treat this as a generic case, there are so many exceptions (esp. in current day scenario)...right?

Comment: No. It is just that mother is more compassionate, so mother is seen to be great. In fact in our Scriptures, father is given a lot of respect. The cultural portrait is based on people. In fact Scriptures too were but the arguments of philosophies of great men. At times they call Guru great, at time Mother, at times Father. But main thing is the Liberation of Soul from Transmigration.